# Text selection in Preview only selects most bottom line, while highlighting a whole column

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a scanned document with OCR. In Adobe Acrobat, I can select and copy words without a problem (first screenshot, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/190m4.jpg)). However, if I open the very same document in Preview and try to select the very same words, Preview instead selects the respective words at the very bottom of the respective page, while showing a selection/highlighting area (in light blue) that stretches over the whole height of the page (second screenshot, [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXcJx.jpg)).

(Copying the selection captures the correct word in Adobe Acrobat, while it captures the respective bottom line instead of the selection in Preview.)

Is there some way to get Preview to have correctly? (I am running MacOS 11.6.2. and have not installed any Preview-related Add-Ons.)

[image: Adobe Acrobat]
[image: Preview]

Comment: Try holding Alt/Option and selecting an area. PDFs don't always store text in a linear order.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this, but to no avail. I selected a whole paragraph and the only word that became selected was an italicized one: ![screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/y1y4Mmz)

Comment: Can you supply a sample of the PDF?

Comment: I have a similar problem with Adobe Acrobat (but not Preview) recognizing that the text has a two column layout. So, the two apps obviously render the same document in very different ways, but I can't see the logic begin it. So, I would say it is a bug in Preview.